# WooCommerce: Change template for single product page

Tags: templates, woocommerce-offtopic

I know there is a possibility to change the structure/design of the product page by editing the file `single-product-php` - in a child-theme.

The changes made of that file will affect all the product pages.

But how do I change the template file for specific product pages? Like I can with a custom page template? From scratch there is no template dropdown on a single product page like there is for a page (the image).

How do I change the template of a specific product page?

[image]

Comment: That dropdown you see on the edit page screen is only available for pages. Possible duplicate question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35221/how-to-get-template-drop-down-menu-in-page-attributes-of-custom-post-type
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652817/select-template-menu-for-custom-post-types

Comment: [You may be interested in the WooCommerce site proposal!](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80132/woocommerce)

Answer (score 9):

Woo Commerce is off topic as its a plugin and not specifically related to WordPress but what you can do is copy over the single-product.php template to a WooCommerce folder in your child theme. change the file name and modify the file, then use [`single_template`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/single_template) or [`template_include`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) with the correct conditional tag.

**single_template**

```
function get_custom_post_type_template($single_template) {
 global $post;

 if ($post->post_type == 'product') {
      $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/single-template.php';
 }
 return $single_template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'get_custom_post_type_template' );
```

**template_include**

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'portfolio_page_template', 99 );

function portfolio_page_template( $template ) {

    if ( is_page( 'slug' )  ) {
        $new_template = locate_template( array( 'single-template.php' ) );
        if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            return $new_template ;
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
```

Comment: None of these fully answer the question, which was "how do I change the template file for specific product pages?"

Answer (score 2):

You need to check WordPress [template-hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) how it works.

Single Post #

The single post template file is used to render a single post. WordPress uses the following path:

```
1.single-{post-type}.php – First, WordPress looks for a template for the specific post type. For example, post type is product, WordPress would look for single-product.php.
2.single.php – WordPress then falls back to single.php.
3.index.php – Finally, as mentioned above, WordPress ultimately falls back to index.php.
```

Page #

The template file used to render a static page (page post-type). Note that unlike other post-types, page is special to WordPress and uses the following patch:

```
   1. custom template file – The page template assigned to the page. See get_page_templates().
   2. page-{slug}.php – If the page slug is recent-news, WordPress will look to use page-recent-news.php.
   3.page-{id}.php – If the page ID is 6, WordPress will look to use page-6.php.
   4. page.php
   5. index.php
```

For specific id you can use `page-{id}.php` template.