# Woocommerce - Change the template?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, templates

I found the solution here [WooCommerce: Change template for single product page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190335/woocommerce-change-template-for-single-product-page)

But, it doesn't actually explain how to do it.. or i'm just not understanding enough.
I did give it a go and placed that text in the "single-product.php", changing where it says dirname to/products.php (my template file name), but nothing changed.

When I go to the product page, I want to be able to use that drop down box that should appear on the right of the page to change the default template as the style on the product page is incorrect.

Can someone please dumb this down for me? I'm pulling my hair out as that's the only thing left to do on my website, I can then make it live.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The dropdown box that you are talking about is for custom WordPress template that WordPress supports by default.

In order to override woocomerce template e.g. `single-product.php`
what  you have to do is to create a folder with name `woocommerce` inside your theme folder e.g.

```
/wp-content/themes/{your_theme_name}/woocommerce/
```

and copy the file from `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product.php` into your theme's woocommerce directory e.g.

```
/wp-content/themes/{your_theme_name}/woocommerce/single-product.php
```

Now its properly override and you can make changes in `single-product.php` within your theme.

This way your changes will remain intact even if you update woocommerce plugin.

To know in detail about woocomerce template overriding see this [link](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Edit:

**Declaring WooCommerce support in themes**

Declaring WooCommerce support is straightforward and involves adding one function in your theme's functions.php file.

```
function mytheme_add_woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_add_woocommerce_support' );
```

Comment: Thank you. I've done as you've advised but it still doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Did you [add_theme_support](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Declaring-WooCommerce-support-in-themes) too?

Comment: @LaurenceReeves Yes, do check if you have added the WooCommerce support for your theme. I have update my answer.