# Custom page type - template under page attributes?

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, page-attributes

I thought we can apply templates to [custom page types](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35221/how-to-get-template-drop-down-menu-in-page-attributes-of-custom-post-type):

> You can't apply templates to custom post types in this manner. That
>   will show up only if the post type is 'page'

My code:

```
function keyword_pages_init() {
    $args = array(
      'label' => 'Keywords',
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'keywords'),
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-page',
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'excerpt',
            'trackbacks',
            'custom-fields',
            'comments',
            'revisions',
            'thumbnail',
            'author',
            'page-attributes',
            )
        );
    register_post_type( 'keywords', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'keyword_pages_init' );
```

But the `template` is not shown up under `page attributes` at all when I try to add a new page under this custom page type.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use custom post  templates, I posted an example [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/244373/26350).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you referring to the new [Post Type Templates feature included in 4.7](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/11/03/post-type-templates-in-4-7/)?

To make a [page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use) available to your 'keywords' cpt you'll want to add a header like this to a custom page template.

```
/**
 * Template Name: Template Name
 * Template Post Type: post, page, keywords
 */
```

This template would be available to all posts, pages, and your keywords cpt. Here is an example of a full page template...

```
<?php
/**
 * ACF Flexible Content template
 *
 * Learn more: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package YM
 * @since   1.0
 * @version 1.0
 */

/**
 * Template Name: Flexible Content
 * Template Post Type: post, page, product, event
 */



/**
 * Add landing page body class to the head
 *
 * @param $classes
 * @return array
 */
add_filter( 'body_class', function ( $classes ) {
    $classes[] = 'flexible-content-template';
    return $classes;
} );



/**
 * Remove entry header
 */
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_do_post_title' );



/**
 * Force full width layout
 */
add_filter( 'genesis_pre_get_option_site_layout', '__genesis_return_full_width_content' );



/**
 * Remove breadcrumbs
 */
remove_action( 'genesis_before_loop', 'genesis_do_breadcrumbs' );



/**
 * Add ACF Flexible Content. See inc/layout.php
 *
 * @uses ym_flexible_content();
 */
remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' );
add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'ym_flexible_content' );



genesis();
```

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/11/03/post-type-templates-in-4-7/